# NextJS errorMessage: "Response payload size exceeded maximum allowed payload size (6291556 bytes)"

Tags: next.js, payload

It seems the response from my API request payload is much in terms of size, whenever I visit the page where this response is rendered, I get this message

```
{
"errorMessage": "Response payload size exceeded maximum allowed payload size (6291556 bytes).",
"errorType": "Function.ResponseSizeTooLarge"
}
```

How am I supposed to manipulate this response to avoid this error on my NextJS application?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this issue,

### 1. How do you handle the error from showing up

*If you are in control of the API*

Check for the response length and send appropriate headers - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504772/13749957

*If you are not in control of the API*

This is just your application handling the error and looking for the `errorType` and informing the user - If you have a mechanism to get a summarized or a fallback api use that.

### 2. If you are in control of the API, compressing or manipulating the response.

1. If the response payload is binary - say an asset, you could look at compression before sending or via a transcoder like `cloudinary` to get a smaller response.
2. If the response payload can be gzipped and isn't already, gzip it before sending.

This article discusses how to get a gzip going on api's https://techblog.commercetools.com/gzip-on-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-5170bb02b543